# .jar program not operating the same as compiled program

Tags: java

I made a simple java program to move the mouse cursor 1 pixel every 10 seconds. The program works as its supposed to when compiled and ran from command line. But when running the program from the .jar the cursor doesnt move. I know the timer is still running because I have that output to the JFrame. Any ideas on why the timer still runs but the cursor doesnt move like it does when ran from command line?

```
public  static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse-Mover");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 300);
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    frame.add(stopButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //when start button is clicked, start the timer
    startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int cursorPositionX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                int cursorPositionY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
                int firstX = cursorPositionX + 1;
                int firstY = cursorPositionY + 1;

                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();
                    robot.mouseMove(firstX, firstY);

                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Running: " + new java.util.Date());
                JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
                jTextArea.setEditable(false);
                jTextArea.setText("Running: " + "X Coordinate: "+firstX + " " + "Y Coordinate: " + firstY + " " + new java.util.Date());
                frame.add(jTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.add(jTextArea);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                stopButton.addActionListener(e -> timer.cancel());
                //system.out.print size of jframe
                System.out.println(frame.getSize());
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    });}}
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by "running from .jar" and how does it differ from "command line"?

Comment: Swing is not thread safe - using `java.util.Timer` will invalidate the non-thread safety of the API.  Also, on each iteration of the timer, you're adding ANOTHER `ActionListener` to the `stopButton` and creating ANOTHER `JTextArea` - this is going to cause you no end of issues ... and confusion

Comment: When I run a modified version of your code on MacOS, I'm provided by a security prompt.  It's possible that the OS is preventing you from interacting with the mouse cursor due to security restrictions

Answer (score 1):

A **.jar** is a compiled application.

Below is an example runnable of how this can be done. Do keep in mind however, as already stated within comments, this may not work properly or (not work at all) on some platforms due to security reasons. Some platforms may not allow for access to low-level input control. You would need to set special privileges or extensions in the OS for your application to function properly.

**Please read the comments in code:**

```
package movemouseeveryseconddemo;

public class MoveMouseEverySecondDemo {

    public int interval = 1000;
    public int pixelMovementX = 1;
    public int pixelMovementY = 1;
    public javax.swing.Timer moveTimer;
    public java.awt.Robot robot;
    public final javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame("Mouse-Mover");
    public final javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    public int firstX = 0, firstY = 0;

    public MoveMouseEverySecondDemo() {
        try {
            // Initialize robot
            robot = new java.awt.Robot();
        }
        /* Robot may not work in some operating systems due to improper
           permissions. If this is the case then OS configurations will 
           need to be done to allow Robot to function.           */
        catch (SecurityException ex) {
            System.out.println("Permission required for Robot or this application"
                    + "to function within Operating System!");
        }
        /* Just as the Exception Description states. Operating System 
           Configuration will need to be done in order for this application 
           to perform low-level input control such as what Robot does.  */
        catch (java.awt.AWTException ex) {
            System.out.println("The Operating System configuration does not "
                    + "allow low-level input control!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MoveMouseEverySecondDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* See if there are Command-Line arguments...
           Allows for the User to supply a desired Timer Interval and desired pixel 
           X/Y movement amounts. The interval must be in Milliseconds (default is 
           1000 [1 second]) and the pixel movement must be an integer value (default 
           is 1). Any or no Command-Line arguments can be supplied and they can be
           supplied in any order.    */
        if (args.length > 0) {
            for (String arg : args) {
                String value = "";
                String cma = arg.contains(":") ? arg.split(":")[0].toLowerCase() : arg.toLowerCase();
                switch (cma) {
                    case "-help":
                    case "/help":
                    case "/?":
                    case "-?":
                        displayHelp();
                        System.out.println();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                    case "/i":
                    case "-i":
                        value = arg.split(":")[1].trim();
                        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid value (" + value + ") supplied to the /I:[n] command-line parameter!");
                            System.out.println("Ignoring this argument and default of " + this.interval + " will be used!");
                            break;
                        }
                        this.interval = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        break;
                    case "/x":
                    case "-x":
                        value = arg.split(":")[1].trim();
                        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid value (" + value + ") supplied to the /X:[n] command-line parameter!");
                            System.out.println("Ignoring this argument and default of " + this.pixelMovementX + " will be used!");
                            break;
                        }
                        this.pixelMovementX = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        break;
                    case "/y":
                    case "-y":
                        value = arg.split(":")[1].trim();
                        if (!value.matches("\\d+")) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid value (" + value + ") supplied to the /Y:[n] command-line parameter!");
                            System.out.println("Ignoring this argument and default of " + this.pixelMovementY + " will be used!");
                            break;
                        }
                        this.pixelMovementY = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid command-line argument supplied! (" + arg + ")");
                        System.out.println("This argument will be ignored!");
                }
            }
        }

        // Initialize the timer.
        moveTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(interval, new moveTimerActionListener());

        // Set some JFrame properties
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 300);

        /* Set up a Window Listener for JFrame to detect when it's
           closing so that the Timer can stopped if it's running 
           and, return an application Exit indicator for the Console.  */
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // If the timmer is running then stop it.
                if (moveTimer.isRunning()) {
                    moveTimer.stop();
                    System.out.printf("%-13s | %-25s%n", "Timer Stopped", getCurrentDateTime());
                    System.out.println("Timer Stopped!");
                }
                System.out.println("Application Closed!");

                // Shut down application.
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // Create the Start button and add to JFrame
        javax.swing.JButton startButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Start");
        frame.add(startButton, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Set some JTextArea properties and add JTextArea to JFrame
        jTextArea.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea.setText("NOT RUNNING:   Mouse X: 0 - Mouse Y: 0  |  Date-Time: "
                + getCurrentDateTime());
        frame.add(jTextArea, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Create the Stop button and add to JFrame
        javax.swing.JButton stopButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Stop");
        frame.add(stopButton, java.awt.BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Set the JFrame to center Screen and make it visible.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /* The Start Button ActionPerformed event. When the `Start` 
           button is selected, the timer starts.         */
        startButton.addActionListener(e -> {

            /* If User tries to Start the Timer while it's already 
               running then prevent it and indicate `No Can Do` in
               the Console and JTextArea.                       */
            if (moveTimer.isRunning()) {
                String curDateTime = getCurrentDateTime();
                jTextArea.setText("Failed Start! Timer is still running!  " + curDateTime);
                System.out.printf("%-13s | %-25s%n", "Failed Start", curDateTime);
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                System.out.println("--     Failed To Restart!    --");
                System.out.println("--  Timer is still running!  --");
                System.out.println("--     Press STOP Button!    --");
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            }
            // Otherwise, indicate the timer has started.
            else {
                moveTimer.start();
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                System.out.println("-- Timer Started! --");
                System.out.println("--------------------");

                // Header Line in console for output data.
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------"
                        + "--------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("   Status             Date - Time           "
                        + "  Form Dimensions       Mouse Coordinates");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------"
                        + "--------------------------------------------");
            }
        });

        /* The Stop Button ActionPerformed Event. When stop 
           button is selected, the timer Stops.   */
        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            // If the `moveTimer` Timer is not running then get otta here.
            if (!moveTimer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            moveTimer.stop();  // Stop the timer.

            String curDateTime = getCurrentDateTime();
            // Place the 'Stopped' fact into the JTextArea.
            jTextArea.setText("NOT RUNNING | STOPPED:   Mouse X: " + firstX
                    + " - " + "Mouse Y: " + firstY + "  |  Date-Time: " + curDateTime);

            // Also place the 'Stopped' fact into the Console Window.
            System.out.printf("%-13s | %-25s%n", "Stopped", curDateTime);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println("-- Timer Stopped! --");
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        });
    }

    public String getCurrentDateTime() {
        /* Establish the current Date-Time using methods from the java.time package.
           These methods a better than the antique & troublesome Date class.      */
        return java.time.LocalDate.now() + " - " + java.time.LocalTime.now();
    }

    private void displayHelp() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("MoveMouseEverySecondDemo Command-Line Help:");
        System.out.println("Command-Line Options:");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("  /? or -? or /help or -help    - This help information.");
        System.out.println("  /I:[value] or -I:[value]      - The interval at which the internal timer");
        System.out.println("                                  should fire. The value provided must be in");
        System.out.println("                                  milliseconds. Default is: 1000.");
        System.out.println("  /X:[value] or -X:[value]      - The desired amount of X axis (horizontal)");
        System.out.println("                                  mouse pointer movement for every fired");
        System.out.println("                                  interval. Default is 1.");
        System.out.println("  /Y:[value] or -Y:[value]      - The desired amount of Y axis (vertical)");
        System.out.println("                                  mouse pointer movement for every fired");
        System.out.println("                                  interval. Default is 1.");
    }

    /* A Inner-Class: The Action Listener for the Timer. On every timer interval, 
       the ActioPerformed Event is fired within this inner-class.                  */
    class moveTimerActionListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            // Establish current date-time for output.
            String curDateTime = getCurrentDateTime();

            // Get the current Mouse Pointer `X` location on the Screen.
            int cursorPositionX = java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            // Get the current Mouse Pointer `Y` location on the Screen.
            int cursorPositionY = java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

            /* Apply the `X` location plus the desired movement amount 
           to the MoveMouseEverySecondDemo class `firstX` member 
           variable.                          */
            firstX = cursorPositionX + pixelMovementX;

            /* Apply the `Y` location plus the desired movement amount 
           to the MoveMouseEverySecondDemo class `firstY` member 
           variable.                          */
            firstY = cursorPositionY + pixelMovementY;

            // Let Robot move the mouse pointer to the new screen location.
            robot.mouseMove(firstX, firstY);

            // Update the information within the JTextArea.
            jTextArea.setText("RUNNING:   " + "Mouse X: " + firstX + " - "
                    + "Mouse Y: " + firstY + "   |   Date-Time: " + curDateTime);

            // Also update the information to Console Window:
            System.out.printf("%-13s | %-25s | %-20s | %-22s%n", "Timer Running", curDateTime,
                    "Form Size: " + frame.getWidth() + ", " + frame.getHeight(),
                    "Mouse X: " + firstX + ", Y: " + firstY);
        }
    }

}
```

This runnable application will run if started from the IDE or if compiled to a JAR file and started from a Command/Console Window. The provided demo application above does of course allow for Command-Line arguments so to change some operational features. They are as follows:

- **/?** or **-?** or **/help** or **-help**:

  Displays help about the Command-Line arguments. Application closes after displaying.
- **/I:***[value]* or **-I:***[value]*:

  The **I**nterval at which the internal timer should fire. The value provided must be in milliseconds. Default is: **1000** (1 second).
- **/X:***[value]* or **-X:***[value]*:

  The desired amount of X axis (horizontal) mouse pointer movement for every fired interval. Default is **1** (DPI or Pixel if you have a real good mouse with a high resolution setting).
- **/Y:***[value]* or **-Y:***[value]*:

  The desired amount of Y axis (vertical) mouse pointer movement for every fired interval. Default is **1** (DPI or Pixel if you have a real good mouse with a high resolution setting).

Any number of command-line arguments can be supplied and they can be supplied in any order. Letter case is also ignored. Any Invalid argument is ignored and its related default will be used.

This demo application will provide information in both the GUI or the Console Window. You choose what you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you for the taking the time to do all of that, your input to this problem is very helpful